# how to use repeater field by relationship manager?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I have a plugin named service. I use a JSON field for service's packages instead of making a table and model for packages and in the backend, I use a repeater to fill this JSON field. How to convert this repeater to a table in backend like a relation config?

Answer (score 0):

To convert a repeater to a table you would need to add each field in your repeater as its own field in the database table, then update your form config to move those fields outside of a repeater.

If you aren't very comfortable with OctoberCMS and how you would go about the above, I would suggest you use the [Builder plugin](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder) to generate the necessary files for you, then review the code that is generated for future reference.

Comment: thanks, I do not use any model or database I want to find some way to use something like relation in my JSON. with another model and table, it is so good but my boss told me to use JSON for that

Comment: @ehsan i guess i am not sure with json you may be able to to do that, or may be if you do it will be really hard. not sure.. just thought